# the mobile page will go above after clicking on the text box

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm building a site which has a mobile branch .
I succeed to build the site as many browsers from PC's can take the same  view and work fine .

now I'm moving to build the site as the mobile can browse the site from maybe mobile chrome or Firefox mobile. I did that but I'm facing a small problem .

many pages of the site has text boxes which you know if you click on it using the mobile
 -for example galaxy note 2 - the soft keyboard will show it self on the screen ,two things happens during this process :

1- the screen will zoom itself until reach the specific text box that you have clicked on.
solution : I solve it by this command   
,so now the screen will not zoom itself.

2- If I have a page which have an including file ,the main div will change his position until reach the above div -included file- and the hall page will be not ordered .

first I will she a brief example about what I mean :

note :my back end is php using Yii framework ,just for info ^_*

page.php:

```
    <div id="div1" style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-bottom: 10px"><?php 

       if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
      include 'flash.php'; ?></div>


      <div id="div2" style="width:100%;position:relative;margin-bottom: 10px">
     <form action="getup" method:"post"> 
     <input type="text"  name="text1" >
     <input type="text" name="text2" >
     // submit button

      </form>
```

now after this brief code , i will show you exactly what is happening , when browse the page from mobile chrome browser the page will be ordered ,but if you click on any text box as text1 for example , what occurs is that DIV2 will move itself up above DIV1
-included file- because the soft keyboard  will show it self on the second half on the screen.

after this example i will oppose my question :

my question is : is there any code -CSS or Java Script - will stop the rising process which is happening to the  DIV2 after the soft keyboard show it self on the mobile screen?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this behavior is related to css you're using? Try removing `position:relative` from your inline style, maybe it will help. Another thing is that input should be self closing tags and div2 closing tag is missing. You don't need to set width of the div tag to 100% as it is its default value.

Comment: this example just to give you a brief idea about my problem , the code is not like that , even if you modify the code as you need , still the problem exist , soft keyboard is a part of IOS android  system. mmm , I try to use the Z index but it is not good choise to me